# Example of use IF in PHP

Tags: php, html

I created this simple Php example to begin my study.

This is Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prova</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="script.php" method="get"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cognome</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cognome" id="cognome"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Invia"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is script.php:

```
<?php
    $cognome = $_REQUEST['cognome'];
    if ($cognome = "Giacomo" )
        {
        echo "<p><img src='Giacomo.jpg'<p>/>";
        }
    else 
        {
        echo "<img src='IMG.jpg'<p>/>";
        }
?>
```

Its run, but if i write Giacomo show Giacomo.jpg and image.jpg. I want only Giacomo.jpg.

Thanks

Comment: As well as the answer below you have HTML errors should be `<p><img src='Giacomo.jpg' /></p>`.

Comment: Your form is sent as a GET request, so you should use the `$_GET` variable. Using the `$_REQUEST` variable may cause unintended problems (unless you specifically design your code to be method agnostic).

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning `$cognome = "Giacomo"` in the `if` statement (which is evaluated to `true` after that), you should compare with `==` or `===` instead:

```
if ($cognome === "Giacomo")
   echo "<p><img src='Giacomo.jpg'></p>";
else
   echo "<p><img src='IMG.jpg'></p>";
```

P.S. It should be `<p></p>` and `<img >`.

Comment: ok notulysse now a can see only one image. But at the end of image  it appear ";} else {echo " this part of the code. Why?

Comment: @Frik: there is only one line proceeding after each `if/else`, so I've omitted curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options:

1) Use the `===` or `==` operator

```
<?php
  $cognome = $_REQUEST['cognome'];
  if ($cognome === "Giacomo")
  {
    echo "<p><img src='Giacomo.jpg'<p>/>";
  } else {
    echo "<img src='IMG.jpg'<p>/>";
  }
?>
```

2) Use the `strcmp` function:

```
<?php
  $cognome = $_REQUEST['cognome'];
  if (strcmp($cognome,"Giacomo") === 0)
  {
    echo "<p><img src='Giacomo.jpg'<p>/>";
  } else {
    echo "<img src='IMG.jpg'<p>/>";
  }
?>
```

I hope I have helped you in it.

Comment: Ahh , if you use the '=' operator you assign the value to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` for comparison, not `=` and you should fix your `HTML` tags like so:

```
<?php
  $cognome = $_REQUEST['cognome'];
  if ($cognome == "Giacomo" )
    {
    echo "<p><img src='Giacomo.jpg'></p>";
    }
  else 
    {
    echo "<p><img src='IMG.jpg'></p>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like notulysses mentioned, using `$cognome = "Giacomo"` will set the variable (even in an if   statement) because of the single `=`

Using `==` is an evaluation, used to question and compare values of the two objects on either side of the `==` but it only compares the value, not the type.

Comparing the value and type is done with `===`
So for example;

```
$number1 = 5;
$number2 = "5"; //notice the quotes
if ($number1 == $number2) { echo "true"; } else { echo "false"; }
// this will echo true
```

However

```
$number1 = 5;
$number2 = "5";
if ($number1 === $number2) { echo "true"; } else { echo "false"; }
// this will echo false`
```

The reason for this is `$number1` is evaluated as a number, while `$number2` is a string because of the quotes.

Another thing I see in your code is

```
echo "<img src='IMG.jpg'<p>/>";
```

should be

```
echo "<p><img src='IMG.jpg' /></p>";
```

And the same goes for your other image.